# Trying to create a table where the columns are IDs, and the rows contain yes/no based on whether or not specific text is linked to the ID

Tags: excel, excel-formula

I would like the result to look something like this.

|  | ID1 | ID2 | ID3 |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| Text 1 | yes | yes | no |
| Text 2 | yes | no | no |
| Text 3 | no | yes | yes |

And I have a table that looks like this. Notice that the text/strings can exist under multiple different IDs. Is there a way to use index/match for this? I've tried to use index/match, but to be honest I don't understand it that well.

| ID1 | ID2 | ID3 |
| --- | --- | --- |
| Text 1 | Text 1 | Text 3 |
| Text 2 | Text 3 | null |
| null | null | null |

See above. I tried to use index/match, and it's just not making sense to me.

Edit: updated the tables so that values match. Sorry!

Comment: Your questions is confusingly worded and I don't understand what you want.  I don't see any clear relationship between your input at the bottom and your output at the top.

Comment: @ScottCraner ooooops, good point. Might help if I made them match. Sorry, I'll edit!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Use a nested INDEX(MATCH) to return the correct column to a MATCH.  Then test if the return is numeric:

```
=IF(ISNUMBER(MATCH($E2,INDEX($A$2:$C$4,0,MATCH(F$1,$A$1:$C$1,0)),0)),"yes","no")
```

[image]